# limit posts pulled in from get_terms

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code, which basically pulls in a list of terms for the taxonomy "categories". It then pulls in every post for that term.

```
 $terms = get_terms('categories');

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'categories','term'=>$term->slug);
  $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
  $article_count = $myquery->post_count;
  echo "<h3 class=\"term-heading\" id=\"".$term->slug."\">";
  echo $term->name;
  echo "</h3>";
  if ($article_count) {
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
      echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
    endwhile;
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}
```

My question is how would i go about limiting the query to only pull in 1 post from each term?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Cheers Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i got working:

i simply changed the following:

```
$wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'categories','term'=>$term->slug,);
```

to:

```
$wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'categories', 'showposts' => 1, 'term'=>$term->slug,);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `post_count` in `$wpq` array

eg:-   `$wpq =  array ('taxonomy'=>'categories','term'=>$term->slug,'post_count' => 1);`

More about WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: thanks, post_count didnt quite work, so i used "showposts" instead

Comment: Consider changing 'showposts' to 'posts_per_page', as 'showposts' was deprecated.